# Can we always construct a sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 1}$ such that it is dense in $X$ and $x_k \in \text{int}(X), \forall k$ for a compact set $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Can we always construct a sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 1}$ such that it is dense in $X$ and $x_k \in \text{int}(X), \forall k$ for a compact set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

For example, if a compact set $X$ has a isolated point, then it seems impossible.
I guess that if $X$ has no isolated point, then it seems possible.
Is there any condition for this? Further, is there any way to construct such dense subset?

EDIT: suppose that $\text{int}(X)$ is nonempty.

EDIT2: Sorry you all. I think that my question is too ambiguous and not clear. I specify my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003302/can-you-make-a-sequence-x-k-k-geq-1-of-elements-in-the-interior-of-k-th).

Comment: Compact sets, not just those without isolated points, may have no interior. For example, $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I forgot the condition of nonempty interior of $X$. I'll update it.

Comment: Just having a dense interior is not enough; in $\mathbb R$ the union of the Cantor set with the closed interval $[3,4]$ is compact and has nonempty interior. What you need is that the interior of $X$ is dense in $X$, and it doesn't matter if $X$ is compact or not.

Comment: Having non empty interior is not enough. Just take the union of the closed disk and a line to see why. As bof said, the interior must be dense; then just order the countable dense subset into a sequence.

Comment: Then which condition may be sufficient for the dense interior? What if $X$ is convex?

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is the Cantor set then it has no isolated points and no point of $C$ is a limit of a sequence from its interior since its interior is empty.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some counterexamples. Is there any case in which such sequence exists?