# Can you make a sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 1}$ of elements in the interior of $K$ that is dense in $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, which is convex and compact?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, compactness

I'm reading a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8715799) about approximators.
In the proof of Theorem 2 in the paper,
the authors mentioned that there is a sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 1}$ of elements in the interior of $K$ that is dense in $K$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and compact and has nonempty interior.

The example suggested in the paper is as follows:
"the set of vectors in the interior of $K$ that have rational coordinates, so by indexing its elements in an arbitrary way, we get a sequence that is dense in $K$."

Is it true?
It seems work intuitively, but I don't know how to show it in a rigorous way.

Comment: There are two statements here: 1) the set of vectors with rational coordinates in $K$ is dense in $K$, and 2) the set of vectors with rational coordinates in $K$ is countable. Which one are you having trouble with? And where exactly do you get stuck when you try to work through it?

Comment: Actually I was struggling with dealing with "int($K$)". Probably @daw 's answer would solve my question. I'll take a look at his/her answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is convex and closed with non-empty interior, then $K$ is equal to the closure of its interior, $K= cl \ int \ K$.

Since $\mathbb Q^n$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$ and $int \ K$ is open, the set $int \ K \cap \mathbb Q^n$ is dense in $int \ K$. Since the closure of $int\ K$ is $K$, these rational points are dense in $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)